# How to display results from mysqli prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

Working on this bit of PHP (just started and have been looking at the documentation). I have a form on another page and everything is passing correctly and the query is returning results (it's meant to search and return the results of user search). The number of rows are displaying correctly so the results are right but the several options I have tried have failed in displaying the results. I just want to display the results from the returned rows. Also if there is any advice on how to simplify the prepare statement and bind, I haven't found a ton of examples with LIKE and % searching multiple columns like below. Thanks

```
<?php
echo "<div class='result-count'>";

if(isset($_POST['keywords'])){

  $keywords = $con->escape_string($_POST['keywords']);
  #$keywords = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","", $keywords);

  $query = $con->prepare(" SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, email
    FROM users
    WHERE firstname LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
    OR lastname LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
    OR firstname LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
    OR phone LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
    OR email LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
  ");

  $query->bind_param("sssss", $keywords, $keywords, $keywords, $keywords, $keywords);
  $query->execute();
  $query->store_result();
  $num_of_rows = $query->num_rows;
#WORKS ABOVE ^

  $query->bind_result($id, $first_name, $last_name, $phone, $email, $address);
#  echo $keywords ;
  if($num_of_rows){
    while($r = $query->fetch()){
      echo $r->user_id;
    }
  }
  else {
        echo $num_of_rows . ' results found.';
  }
}
echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. The first is that you are binding 6 results, but your query only returns 4. The second is that `mysqli_stmt::fetch` simply returns a boolean indicating success/fail since all result data is fetched into the bound result parameters. For your query as is, you need to do something like:

```
$query->bind_result($first_name, $last_name, $phone, $email);
while ($query->fetch()) {
    echo $first_name, $last_name, $phone, $email;
}
```

Notes:

1. Since you are using a parameterised query, you don't need to use `escape_string` on your inputs.
2. It's more efficient to add the `%` to either side of the parameter *once* in PHP (i.e. `$keywords = "%$keywords%";`) and just use `LIKE ?` rather than 5 instances of `LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Nick said. Your main mistake is the confusion with how `bind_result()/fet ch()` works. For this reason let me suggest `fetch_all()`. It reads all results into a simple multi-dimensional array in PHP. You can then loop it like any other array.

```
<?php
echo "<div class='result-count'>";

if (isset($_POST['keywords'])) {

    $keywords = '%' . $_POST['keywords'] . '%';

    $query = $con->prepare(" SELECT firstname, lastname, phone, email
        FROM users
        WHERE firstname LIKE ?
        OR lastname LIKE ?
        OR firstname LIKE ?
        OR phone LIKE ?
        OR email LIKE ?
    ");

    $query->bind_param("sssss", $keywords, $keywords, $keywords, $keywords, $keywords);
    $query->execute();
    $users = $query->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    #  echo $keywords ;
    if ($users) {
        foreach ($users as $r) {
            echo $r['firstname'];
        }
    } else {
        echo '0 results found.';
    }
}
echo "</div>";
```

Other points:

- Don't use `escape_string()`
- You don't need `num_rows`
- You have firstname twice in the WHERE clause